# Byteman 4.0.11 not entirely published to Maven Central?

Tags: byteman

The Byteman website advertises version 4.0.11 as released: https://byteman.jboss.org/downloads.html

But only some artifact IDs are available on Maven Central: https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:org.jboss.byteman

Did something go wrong during the release? Did artifact IDs change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this. There was no problem reported during the maven build or upload to the Sonatype repo and my release of the artefacts was indicated as successful. However, Sonatype has been rather flaky recently. It seems to have lost many of the artefacts at release (before transfer to Maven Central).

I have hand uploaded all the missing artefacts for 4.0.11 to Sonatype and checked that they are all currently resident in their repo. I also checked and the 3.0.18 artefacts (originally released at the same time) also seem to be present on their site. These all ought to get pushed over to Maven Central soon. If that doesn't happen within a day or two (worst case) then that probably means the Sonatype copying operation is wedged again. Let me know if so and I will raise the transfer problem with them. Let's keep our finger crossed they don't lose the uploads.